# Jumbo Frames not sliding for CentOS 8 gues on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, mtu, centos-8

Have a super strange issue. Any CentOS 8 guest I build on one of my Hyper-V servers with MTU 9000 (Jumbo Frames) Has extremely poor performance when accessing the internet (being less than 9K MTU). This is only with CentOS 8 installs on one Hyper-V server.

My network is 9K MTU to include all hypervisors, switches, etc. Other than the CentOS 8 guest installs on this one Hyper-V server, everything else is verified to be working. NOTE: the CentOS 8 guest has no problems and performs perfectly to anything within the network. (uploads/downloads). This only affects the guest performance to the internet.

What I've tried (everything is set to 9K MTU):

- I have a twin CentOS 8 guest on a Twin Hyper-V (same NIC and same Storage type) and it has no issues I move the guest to the other Hyper-V server and internet performance is poor. Move back, and internet performance is fine.
- I've built (and currently run) CentOS 7 guests on the Hyper-V servers
  with no issue.
- I have Windows guests on the Hyper-V running with no issue.
- I build a CentOS 8 guest VM on the one Hyper-V server, which has the
  issue, and moved it to the other server, which cleared the issue.

I'm focused on the MTU as when I use 1500 MTU on the CentOS 8 Guest, where is no issue with internet performance, but once I set it to 9K MTU, it's a tenth of the performance to the internet, compared to any other VM in the farm (including other CentOS 8 Guests).

Also focused on the single Hyper-V server as it is only on this one Hyper-V server and no other system. 
Any ideas how to dig into this one?
UPDATE: I tried to remove the NetworkManager and see if the performance was resolve and it did not help. Last option is to reinstall the Hyper-V server unless anyone else has ideas.. help?
-Mak